# Returning File Fields through Many to Many Relationship in Django for Zipview

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to dynamically zip audio files that are linked using [django-zipview](https://github.com/thibault/django-zipview). However I do not seem to be able to feed it the correct inputs.

Sounds have a file and sounds can be a part of a release or many releases. I would like to (for now at least) dynamically serve zip files containing all sounds in a release when the user hit's the url: `url(r'^release/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/download$', views.ReleaseArchiveView.as_view(), name='release_download'),` (The URL works fine)

**Models.py** (irrelevant fields removed)

```
class Release(models.Model):
  sound = models.ManyToManyField(Sound)
  release_title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
  slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='release_title',unique=True)

class Sound(models.Model):
  sound_title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
  file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_path,blank=True)
  slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from=('sound_title'),unique=True)
```

**Views.py**

```
class ReleaseArchiveView(BaseZipView):
model = Release

def get_files(self):
    release = Release.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug']) 
    return Sound.objects.filter(release__slug=release)
```

According to the documentation django-zipview simply needs a list of the filefields from Sounds. However I cannot find the correct query to allow me to pass this. At present I am simply being returned an empty zip file.

How can I pass a list of FileFields in the manner that django-zipview is expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to have a look again at the [django-zipview](https://github.com/thibault/django-zipview) page on GitHub that you linked to, where they provide exactly the example you need:

```
class ReleaseArchiveView(BaseZipView):
    model = Release

    def get_files(self):
        sounds =  Sound.objects.filter(release__slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))
        return [s.file.file for s in sounds if s.file.name]
```

You were missing the last part, where they return a list of file objects.

Also your code here didn't really make sense I think:

```
release = Release.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug']) 
return Sound.objects.filter(release__slug=release)
```

...you were passing a `Release` instance as the `slug` value, when I guess you really meant `release.slug`. But anyway, it appears you have `release` as a foreign key on the `Sound` model so you don't need to get the release first.

Comment: Perfect. The last answer helped me get closer to the required query but was raising attribute errors when hitting the URL. Your answer has just made it work perfectly. I was finding the example difficult to follow as they have not provided the models in there. Altho I can see that it is pretty simple. I guess I just needed a fresh pair of eyes!

Answer (score -1):

```
return Sound.objects.filter(release__slug=release)
```

Returns the entire queryset. If you want to return just the file names, you will have to return just the values:

```
return list(Sound.objects.filter(release__slug= self.kwargs['slug']).values_list('file', flat=True))
```

Which will return a list of file names

see [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) docs

Comment: Thanks, I had to change it slightly to get it to work but it also resulted in less code too :)  

`return Sound.objects.filter(release__slug=self.kwargs['slug']).values_list('file', flat=True)'`